# python web3, given only token address, fetch liquidity pool details from pancake swap

Tags: web3.py, pancakeswap

Using python 3.10, web3 v5.31.1

Given only the contract address for a single token (tokenA), is there a method from PancakeSwap to return liquidity pool (LP) details?

Mainly given only the address of tokenA, how can I find out what LP is set up for tokenA?

Furthermore, assuming I want to buy tokenA with BNB, but tokenA has a LP with some other token, tokenB, but tokenB has an LP with BNB, I can swap via BNB -> tokenB -> tokenA.

How do dApps such as https://poocoin.app find these routes to trade. The image below shows that the dApp found a valid route BNB -> BUSD -> USDT -> token. How is this accomplished?

[image: screenshot of poocoin.app swap example]

I am new to coding web3 so example code would be greatly appreciated; thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `PAIRS_TO_CHECK_TRADE_AGAINS` addresses. Check within the factory if there's pairs between your token and `WBNB`, `BUSD`, `TETHER` and `USDC`. Maybe `WBTC`.

You can check calling `getPool()` from the pancake factory, pass the address of your token and the addresses of those tokens. With the address the pool you can do everything else.